# Вывод значения поля mysql, заключенного в кавычки

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго дня!

Кто-нибудь объясните, пожалуйста, мне непутёвому, как правильно вывести значение из базы mysql, если часть его заключена в кавычки. Вот конкретный случай. В базе, в одной из строк, в колонке "org_name" есть запись: ОАО "Ростелеком". В php скрипте есть место, в котором необходимо вывести эту запись, а именно:

```
<input type="text" name="ORG_NAME" value="'.$row['org_name'].'">
```

В итоге в форме в качестве значения вписывается ОАО, а "Ростелеком" теряется... Как можно это побороть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите функцию [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

То есть в вашем примере полностью будет так:

```
<input type="text" name="ORG_NAME" value="' . htmlspecialchars($row['org_name']) .'">
```

И вот что важно. Вообще говоря, вы должны пропускать через эту функцию не только «значение, заключенное в кавычки», а вообще все строки, в которых потенциально могут встретиться кавычки, амперсанды и знаки больше и меньше.

А если это значение в базу данных еще и не вы сами положили, а приняли из пользовательского ввода — то сразу «здравствуй, XSS».

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ!!!Это именно то,что я искал!